# Determine if a line will interest with a rectangular prism

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

Alright lets say I have 2 points in 3 dimensional space how could I determine if a line interesting those 2 points will pass through a rectangular prism when all I have is that prisms min and max value for all 3 coordinates? Is there an easy way I can check for an intersection here?

I found this which is similar to my question however it does not seem to be answered either. The last comment left on the post has an example that is similar to what I would be doing since they defined the box with its min and max values.
[How to check if an infinite line intersects a rectangular prism in 3d space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134505/how-to-check-if-an-infinite-line-intersects-a-rectangular-prism-in-3d-space)

My end goal is to be able to throw it into software to be able to detect intersections however I am not sure how I am suppose to actually create a useable formula from the info given on that post.

Comment: It's "intersect", not "interest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the line as $(a_1, a_2, a_3) + t (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and the rectangular prism as $[c_1, d_1] \times [c_2, d_2] \times [c_3, d_3]$. For a point of the line to intersect the prism, there must be a value of $t$ such that
$$
   \begin{cases}c_1 \le a_1 + t b_1 \le d_1 \\ 
      c_2 \le a_2 + tb_2 \le d_2 \\
      c_3 \le a_3 + tb_3 \le d_3
   \end{cases}
$$

Each inequality $c_i \le a_i + tb_i \le d_i$ (for $i=1, 2, 3$) is solved in the same way, but the result depends on the sign of $b_i$:

- If $b_i > 0$, then we get $\frac{c_i - a_i}{b_i} \le t \le \frac{d_i - a_i}{b_i}$.
- If $b_i < 0$, then we instead get $\frac{d_i - a_i}{b_i} \le t \le \frac{c_i - a_i}{b_i}$, because dividing by $b_i$ reverses the inequalities.
- If $b_i = 0$, then either $c_i \le a_i \le d_i$ (and the inequality is true for all $t$), or not (and the inequality is false for all $t$).

We'll get several lower and upper bounds on $t$. If the largest lower bound is less than or equal to the smallest upper bound, then we can combine them to get an interval of $t$-values that work. (This can be used to find all the points where the line intersects the prism.)

If the largest lower bound is bigger than the smallest upper bound, or if one of the inequalities we started with was false for all $t$, then there is no intersection.

---

For example, suppose we want to intersect the line through $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$ with the prism $[-1,1] \times [0,5] \times [4,6]$.

We rewrite the line as $(1,2,3) + t(2,0,-2)$, and get the three inequalities
$$
   \begin{cases}-1 \le 1 + 2t \le 1 \\ 
      0 \le 2 + 0t \le 5 \\
      4 \le 3 - 2t \le 6
   \end{cases}
$$
The first inequality $-1 \le 1+2t \le 1$ simplifies to $-2 \le 2t \le 0$ and then to $-1 \le t \le 0$. That's our first interval for $t$: the interval $[-1,0]$.

The second inequality $0 \le 2 + 0t \le 5$ does not depend at all on $t$. Luckily for us, it's true. (If it were false, we'd already know there's no intersection.)

The third inequality $4 \le 3-2t \le 6$ simplifies to $1 \le -2t \le 3$ and then to $-\frac32 \le t \le -\frac12$. That's our second interval for $t$: the interval $[-\frac32, -\frac12]$.

The intersection of these intervals is $[-1,0] \cap [-\frac32, -\frac12]$ is $[-1, -\frac12]$, so for any $t$ in this range, the line is inside the prism. (In particular, the line does intersect the prism.) For example, when $t = -\frac34$, the point $(1,2,3) - \frac34 (3,2,1) = (-\frac54, \frac12, \frac94)$ is inside the prism.

Comment: What exactly is ci, ai,, bi, and di because you never defined what those variables represent. Also I am still not sure how I am suppose to find t.

Comment: @UnSure They are defined in the first paragraph. Misha is using the vector form for a line in $3$ dimensions, which involves an initial point $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ on the line (doesn't matter which one) and a direction vector $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ (a non-zero vector parallel to the line). The $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are respectively the lower bounds on the $x, y, z$-coordinates of the box, and $d_1, d_2, d_3$ are the respective upper bounds.

Comment: @Misha +1, but I think this answer could be improved by including an illustrative example of this computation.

Comment: Yes an example would be helpful because I am still slightly confused. Also "i" is not talked about at all until he said ci <= ai. So what does he mean by "i"? I have no trouble understanding the first paragraph however the second part confuses me since "i" was not defined. Also I understand that the c and d points represent the rectangular prism however I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Since there are three inequalities and they're all solved in the same way, I am using $i$ for the number of the inequality we're on. We do this for $i=1$, then $i=2$, then $i=3$.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Alright thank you that makes sense but I still dont see how I am suppose to solve the problem since all you provided are logical inequalities which I understand now but I still dont know how to solve this problem. Maybe ill try to ask some where else thanks for trying though.

Comment: I'm sorry for only providing logical inequalities. Would you like some illogical ones?

Comment: Thats not what I am saying lmao I was trying to think how I could turn something that was logically obvious into something a computer could understand. Thanks for providing an example.

Comment: The first part of the answer is closer to what the code will look like. Just think through what the obvious things to do are in the example, and try to ask yourself what the calculations you're actually doing are.

Comment: I turned it the equation of the line into parametric form but I cant figure out where to go from there.